# AWS equivalent for Azure Resourcegroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

Azure Resource group is one thing which ties one complete stack together, so in case you want to know what your complete stack looks like just open up your RG and all resources are there(not talking about very big stacks ). 
Do we have any service in AWS like this ??

Comment: There is something called Resource Group in AWS but it feels very different than in azure. I will admit, I have used aws for a long time but have never bothered to use it. see here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/welcome.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AWS also has Resource Groups. It's not identical to Azure resource groups. But it will work for your need. You need to use tags for the resources and then group them using AWS Resource Groups. Tags are very powerful and widely used in AWS.

Comment: Can you also define who can read, edit, create entries in the tag controlled aws resource groups views, i.e. setup rbac [ role based access control ] to them?

Comment: Yes, you can use tags to control access to your AWS resources. You can use conditions in your IAM policies to control access to AWS resources based on the tags on that resource. This IAM policy can be applied to IAM users or roles. For more details -https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_tags.html

Comment: Far from equivalent in terms of effort surely? What I mean is it seems far easier to forget to tag an resource in AWS than to select a mandatory resource group in Azure. Now what does an account look like in AWS when you forgot to tag 100 times across a range of business units?

Answer (score 6):

An AWS Cloudformation template creates a "Stack" with all the resources defined in the template. In the AWS console what you see under the Cloudformation service are these stacks. They seem to me to be very much like an Azure Resource Group. The life cycle of the resources in the template are managed by the stack. If you delete the stack all the resources are deleted; very much like an Azure Resource Group.

Answer (score 3):

I've been playing in Azure for a while with Kubernetes (AKS) and Terraform. I was used to deploying an Azure resource group and everything in it:

- Key vault
- storage account
- DataBricks
- Data Factory
- SQL Server (or some other database)

Simple enough. So, I just tried to deploy a similar data stack in AWS. It's not at all the same, and a lot more effort.

1. The VPC seems is the first place to start. You'll also have to
   think about CIDR addresses too.
2. Subnets (you'll be defining CIDR blocks here too), and deciding availability zones come next.
3. You'll also need security groups.

You'll also need IAM resources and to attach the relevant roles/policies.  In Azure, once permissions and Service Principals are in place, you don't have to worry about all these things.

All this is before you've deployed anything.

Now, that's my immediate feeling trying to replicate what I was doing on Azure. I didn't let how long it takes to deploy these resources on AWS (like 30 mins in the EU region - YMMV - but much longer compared to Azure)  cloud my judgement either...

A Cloudformation 'stack' was created when I tested using the AWS EKSCLI command line tool to provision a kubernetes cluster and nodes. Deleting a stack on Cloudformation will remove all the associated resources, like if you were to remove a resource group on Azure.

I think, using Terraform is probably a good idea, which is the conclusion you may arrive at after having to chase down why you can't delete a certain resource, because something is still using it (and it's not all in the same place as other things like in an Azure resource group.

Comment: you can also provision Databricks in AWS - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/guides/aws-workspace

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments you can group together AWS resources using resource groups. If you are looking for more than mere grouping then there is [AWS OpsWorks Stacks](https://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/stacks/). AWS OpsWorks Stacks is nothing but chef under the hood. Here you can get the full view of associated resources and you can manage as well.